# PHP echoing <tagname> doesn't display

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a string with tags which is used in my API to send to Sage. Because it's in an API i cant change content type to xml or plain text. This is my string :

```
$mainstringforsage = ($mainstringforsage . ('test1 <Row><CommodityUUID>' . $xsid . '</CommodityUUID><Quantity>' . $xtotalqty . '</Quantity><ActualPrice>' . $xprice . '</ActualPrice><NetTotal>' . $xnet . '</NetTotal><TaxTotal>' . $xtax . '</TaxTotal><GrossTotal>' . $xgross . '</GrossTotal></Row> test2'));

var_dump($mainstringforsage);
```

And the result for this is

> string(176) "test1 1.05000 test2"

Is the a reason anything enclosed in <> is not displaying?

Thanks

Comment: The browser is interpreting those as HTML tags…

Comment: Are you, by any chance, outputting as HTML and viewing in a web browser? (Note that the string length (176) is right, so the tags are definitely in the string; you're just not seeing them.)

Comment: well im looking at the response from the api in the console @MattGibson

Comment: "Because it's in an API i cant change content type to xml or plain text." <<< why not? APIs can respond with whatever content-type they see fit. If your API returns XML, set the content type to application/xml.

Comment: Also, if you are authoring XML, consider using XmlWriter or DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags are currently interpreted by your browser that's the reason why only the text is displayed.
If you just want to check the content of your string you can make it this way:

```
echo htmlentities($mainstringforsage);
```

BTW, for a good practice if your API returns XML you should set the content-type as text/xml :

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: htmlentities is what i was looking for thanks for that.